# how to get the path of an uploaded file in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

how to get the path of an uploaded file in reactjs.
I use the file upload to upload a file

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="file" onChange={this.fileChangedHandler} />
      <button onClick={this.uploadHandler}>Upload!</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

then bind the uploadHandler

```
this.uploadHandler = this.uploadHandler.bind(this)
```

and

```
uploadHandler = () => { 
  console.log("the selected file is : "+this.state.selectedFile.name)
}
```

Here I'm getting its name. I want to get the file path.

Comment: Is your file uploaded into server? If not, you cannot access file path, because there are no path to file uploaded onto the server

Comment: i'm not uploading file to server. Just using file upload..

Comment: In this case, I guess it is not possible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15201258/5709697

Comment: You can't read files, directories in client side with javascript. You need to upload it first and read file path in server side then send response of file's path from server.

Comment: What is your use case? What do you want to do with the file path?

Comment: Thanks for let me know that i can only get the file path from the server and can't read files in client side.. I think that i can grab the file using the file path.. Thanks

Comment: @RenjithStephen You can use a [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) if you want to use the data directly in the browser.

Comment: can i use File Reader for multiple files..?

Comment: Refer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55726630/how-to-display-file-name-with-javascript-after-upload

Answer (score 5):

If you want to upload an **image** without posting to a server, you can use base64.

reactjs:

```
   this.state = {
     imgUpload: '',
   }
```

...

```
  this.getBase64 = this.getBase64.bind(this)
```

...

```
  getBase64(e) {
    var file = e.target.files[0]
    let reader = new FileReader()
    reader.readAsDataURL(file)
    reader.onload = () => {
      this.setState({
        imgUpload: reader.result
      })
    };
    reader.onerror = function (error) {
      console.log('Error: ', error);
    }
  }
```

...

```
  <div>
    <input type="file" className="input-file" name="imgUpload" accept='.png' onChange={this.getBase64} />
  </div>
```

Then you can use `{this.state.imgUpload}` to access the base64 string and can manipulate the image.